# ngx-mask sets ng-pristine to ng-dirty even if no keydown event fired

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page with a form, for some inputs ngx-mask is used to mask input (phone number etc...) If there are any changes in input I check if the input is ng-dirty and show save button.

```
<app-bottom-button *ngIf="(userInformationForm.dirty)"></app-bottom-button>

<form class="mb-35 mb-md-30"
        [formGroup]="userInformationForm">

<input class="floating-label-input" type="text" mask="99-99-9999">
  <label class="floating-label">
     {{'Birthdate'}}
  </label> 
</form>
```

If I click on input and type something(focus -> keydown -> blur),  is shown but if I click on input and click outside without typing anything (focus -> blur)  is still shown. Is there a way to prevent this in ngx-mask?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add a plunk for your code

Comment: That's the `touched/untouched` property, not the `dirty/pristine` one.

Comment: trichetriche, but I check the dirty/pristine case, not touched/untouched case.

Comment: Ms. Tamil, I would love to do that but the project is too complex to create a tiny plunker prototype at the moment.